# android two ScrollViews nested / small horizontal ScrollView in vertical ScrollView

Tags: android, nested, scrollview

I have looked a lot for the answer to the following question but I did not find a proper solution (neither "its impossible"). I don't want a two-way ScrollView!

All I want is having something like that:

```
<ScrollView android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="300px" />
</ScrollView>
```

if I do this (with the required layout attributes) I get my vertical ScrollView scrollable but not the horizontal one. Am I missing something important or is that just not possible with the stock controls?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/my_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="72dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Tab2Headline" 
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You tell us that you do NOT want a 2-way scrollview.
Then you say your example gives you your desired vertical, but not your desired horizontal scrolling.

Huh?

Then the "answer" is to remove the vertical scrolling altogether, and just have it scroll horizontally.

Huh?